# bash cgi won't return image

Tags: perl, bash, cgi, rrd

We have a monitoring system making RRD databases. I am looking for the most light way of creating graphs from this RRD files for our HTML pages. So I don't want to store them in files. I am trying to create simple BASH CGI script, that will output image data, so I can do something like this:

```
<img src="/cgi-bin/graph.cgi?param1=abc"></img>
```

First of all, I am trying to create simple CGI script, that will send me PNG image. This doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: image/png\n\n"
cat image.png
```

But when I rewrite this to PERL, it does work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
open(IMG, "image.png");
print while <IMG>;
close(IMG);
exit 0;
```

What is the difference? I would really like to do this in BASH. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absence of `-n` switch outputs third newline, so it should be

```
echo -ne "Content-type: image/png\n\n"
```

or

```
echo -e "Content-type: image/png\n"
```

from `man echo`

> ```
>   -n     do not output the trailing newline
> ```

Comment: If it's still not working, check the image permissions.